# PHP Onclick Popup

Tags: php

I would like a "popup" to appear when a user clicks the delete button in a CMS.  I have the following code:

```
<?php echo ("<a href='delete_donor.php?id=$row->id' class='delete_icon2' title='Delete Donor' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')'></a></td>");?>
```

I've used the "onclick" option successfully before, but not in a PHP environment.  The above code seems to ignore the "onclick" statement.  I'm thinking I may have an issue with the quotation marks and have tried several other options but to no avail.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: What HTML is actually being rendered to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a PHP issue.

`onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')'`

is not going to work since you use `'` for two different things.

Change it to

`onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this entry?\")'`

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't echo HTML.  Just let PHP output it directly.

```
<a href="delete_donor.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="delete_icon2" title="Delete Donor"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')"></a></td>
```

Anything not inside `<?php ?>` tags is echoed directly to stdout.